# Reflection of comparison phrase

Tags: c#, reflection, parameters, comparison, phrase

Maybe my question weird... I wonderd if it possible to use reflection on a phrase.

I tried to make comparison with reflection in C#. Until now I passed the name of the property as string and the value as object, like that: `Cmp("foo", "abc")`.
In this way I have to check if `foo` is existing property in the class, and check if the value type match the property type (in the example above foo is string property, and the value is string). This way works fine!

I just wonder if it possible to send phrase as parameter and analize it with reflection or something simmilar.
I mean, as in the example above instead of calling the function like that `Cmp("foo", "abc")` just call the function like this `Cmp(A.foo == "abc")` (`A` is class that have `foo` propery), then analize that the property is `foo` and the value is `"abc"`.

I know its sounds weird, and its not necessary for me. Its just for the idea.
Is it possible?

**EDIT**
If I was not clear, I have wrote the `Cmp(string, string)` method, and it works fine!
I just want to know if there is way to write the `Cmp` method like this: `Cmp(A.foo == "abc")`. That the parameter is a phrase.

**EDIT 2**
For example you can do something like it in C. You can create macro like that:

```
#define Cmp(phrase) printf(##phrase)
```

Then if you call it like `Cmp(A.foo == "abc")` the output will be:

> A.foo == "abc"

Like pass the whole phrase as parameter and analize it. I know that macro is pre-compile thing, I just want to know if there is something like that in C#

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you can do `obj.Foo == "abc"`, what does `Cmp` do?

Comment: Sorry I will fix the question, the class that containce `Cmp` containce also the object that have `foo` property. It should be `A.foo == "abc"`

Comment: You might need to post more complete code for this to make sense.

Comment: Basically you want to loop over all the properties of the object you call `Cmp` on and check if it has a property called `Foo` and compare the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [expression trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx) to describe an expression like `bar.Foo == "abc"`. Here is a simple example that assumes the you have a class named `Bar` that has a property named `Foo`:

```
String FormatExpression<T>(Expression<Func<T, Boolean>> expression) {
  if (expression == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("expression");
  var body = expression.Body as BinaryExpression;
  if (body == null)
    throw new ArgumentException(
      "Expression body is not a binary expression.", "expression");
  return body.ToString();
}
```

Calling

```
FormatExpression((Bar bar) => bar.Foo == "abc")
```

will return the string

```
(bar.Foo == "abc")
```

Comment: I wrote already the `Cmp(string, string);`. I just wonder if it posibble to write it like `Cmp(A.foo == "abc");`.

Comment: @Someone: I don't understand your edited question. You surely are not asking about the function `Boolean Cmp(Boolean b) { return b; }` (it satisfies your requirement) so there must be some detail that I'm missing.

Comment: My question is over this. If yue can send hole phrase as parameter.
I will edit again with example from C

Answer (score 0):

This extension method goes through all (readable, public) properties of the object it's called on, checks for a property with the given name on that property and compares the values.

```
public static class CmpExtension
{
    public static bool Cmp<T, TValue>(this T obj, string propertyName, TValue value)
        where TValue : class
    {
        var properties = obj.GetType().GetProperties()
                .Where(p => p.CanRead);

        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            var propertyValue = property.GetValue(obj, null);

            var childProperty = property.PropertyType.GetProperties()
                .Where(p => p.CanRead)
                .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == propertyName);

            if (childProperty == null) continue;

            var childPropertyValue = childProperty.GetValue(propertyValue, null);

            return childPropertyValue == value;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

By using this, you can do:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Bar Bar { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var foo = new Foo { Bar = new Bar { Value = "Testing" } };
    foo.Cmp("Value", "Testing"); // True
}
```

To use the alternative syntax use:

```
public static class CmpExtension
{
    public static bool Cmp<T>(this T obj, Func<T, bool> func)
    {
        return func(obj);
    }
}
```

Using this, you can do

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var foo = new Foo { Bar = new Bar { Value = "Testing" } };
        foo.Cmp(f => f.Bar.Value == "Testing"); // True
    }
```

Comment: I wrote already the `Cmp(string, string);`. I just wonder if it posibble to write it like `Cmp(A.foo == "abc");`.